# indefinite integral in octave

Tags: octave, numerical-integration, octave-gui

I am trying to integrate `x^3/(exp(x)-1)` in the limit 0 to infinity with respect to x,and it should answer `pi^4/15` but it instead of this ocatve is printing original integral in symbolic form. How to resolve this issue? I tried same integral on MATLAB mobile and it is giving correct `pi^4/15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

```
pi^4 / 15 = 6.4939
```

I tried the below code in [octave online](https://octave-online.net/)

```
fun = @(x) (x.^3)./(exp(x)-1); 
q = integral(fun, 0, Inf)
```

The answer is:

```
q = 6.4939
```

Comment: But why this code is not working? syms x ;  int(x^3/(exp(x)-1),0,inf)

Comment: From 0 to Inf, you want to calculate each variable value, i.e. from 0 to Inf calculate the integral based on the formula. To achieve this, you need to do an element-wise calculation. An element-wise calculation syntax is `.` You missed dots between the operations. So the correct formula is (x.^3) ./ (exp(x) - 1)